# What Does the Javascript Spec say should be returned from an out of bounds array index on a NodeList

Tags: javascript, specifications

I recently started a new job working on a browser-based application and am still learning the finer points of Javascript.  I've got a question about what a JS interpreter following the spec should do with the following code snippet.

```
node_list_foo = document.getElementsByName("bar");
//node_list_foo is now a node list with a length of lets say 3.
var element_from_item = NodeListFoo.item(4);
//element_from_item is now NULL according to [url]https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist[/url]
var element_from_index = NodeListFoo[4];
// my broswers are setting element_from_index to undefined in this case, but what should it be?
```

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist appears to defer defining the behavior of out of range indices to the definition of supported-property-indices, am I reading that right?

https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-supported-property-indices has this to say about using array style syntax to access objects with a getter.  NodeList has a relevant getter - item(index).

> If an indexed property getter was specified using an operation with an >identifier, then the value returned when indexing the object with a given >supported property index is the value that would be returned by invoking the >operation, passing the index as its only argument. If the operation used to >declare the indexed property getter did not have an identifier, then the >interface definition must be accompanied by a description of how to determine >the value of an indexed property for a given index.

If I'm reading that right, the spec says the behavior of the two access methods should be the same?  So both should return undefined?

Curiously, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList, documents the observed behavior and not the behavior that I think the spec calls for.

What's the correct interpretation of the spec and is there another approach I should take to finding out how these kinds of things work?

Finally, if my interpretation of the spec is correct; nobody seems to actually follow the spec for using array style syntax; so as a paranoid and perfectionist programmer should I be using nodelist.item(x) as the preferred approach?